# Truths tellers and liars. A short one

Tags: liars, situation

On a strange island five people are living.

Of the one half we know: they only speak the truth,
of the other half we know: they only speak lies.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of them doesn't speak at all.

Comment: I was hoping to get you puzzled at least a while, but no.  2 answers in no time.

Comment: That is basically what my answer said, but I deleted it because it is incorrect. The person who does not speak must be counted also, meaning that the two percentages are not 50%, but 40%.

Comment: The way I see it, "half of them only tell the truth" doesn't mean the other half doesn't.  You could say for instance: "half of them only tell the truth, the other half do the same".  Note that it is not "(half of them only) tell the truth" but "half of them (only tell the truth)".  I'll reformulate the question.

Answer (score 1):

> You are a liar. There is no island.

Comment: It is true.  I always lie.

Comment: This is a [standard loophole](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1335/69582)